# How to load build.gradle task via intelliJ IDE and debug

Tags: groovy, gradle, cucumber-jvm

My requirement is to load `Config.groovy` file when run cucumber tests in `IntellI IDE`. Because I am not able to load config data via `build.gradle` through `IntelliJ`

I stored all environment related data there in `config` file. Currently it is loading perfectly via `build.gradle` when I run test via command line. But only issue is debugging is not possible with command line.

**Versions**

```
IntelliJ : 13.0.3

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 1.9
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2013-11-19 08:20:02 UTC
Build number: none
Revision:     7970ec3503b4f5767ee1c1c69f8b4186c4763e3d

Groovy:       1.8.6
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.2 compiled on July 8 2013
Ivy:          2.2.0
JVM:          1.7.0_45 (Oracle Corporation 24.45-b08)
OS:           Windows 7 6.1 amd64
```

Is there any solution?

Comment: I found alternative way to run the tests via `IntelliJ IDE ` by running the `build.gradle ` task using `Gradke Tool Window `. So then no need of loading `config ` file seperately as its done through `build.gradle `. But question is how to do debug in that way?

Comment: Changed the Question Title to make better scense

Answer (score 2):

Run `gradle test -Dtest.debug=true`, then connect a remote debugger on the port suggested by IntelliJ (5050 I believe).

Comment: Just clarification. Where should I add `gradle test -Dtest.debug=true ` if I run through `IDE `? Because under `Edit Configuration ` there is `remote ` option. But there nothing editable

Comment: Further I am getting `Error running Cucmber: Unable to open debugger port : java.net.SocketException "socket closed ` at the end of debugging session

Comment: I set `GRADLE_OPTS= -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005 ` in `env variables ` and then I could see the message `Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005 ` in the terminal. But even after that when run the task `cucumber ` in debug mode on the IDE it doesn't stop at break points. Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Perhaps `cucumber` is not a `Test` task, in which case this won't work.

Comment: In case if I want to debug groovy class NOT the gradle `task `, what would be the best way?. Because I can't just run the debug option in `IDE ` since in my case I need to run `build.gradle ` first and then the tests(This is to load the config data via `task `) which I do the way I mentioned in my very first comment. When I tried to debug groovy class file in the above method it doesn't stop at break points. What change need to be done.

Comment: Depends on the details of how the Groovy class file gets executed. If it gets executed with a `JavaExec` task, you can configure the task`s `jvmArgs` similar to what you did for `GRADLE_OPTS` above.

Comment: Basically there is only one `task ` called '`cucumber ` is there under `gradle .build ` and loads environmental variables. So if I was to run the tests from the IDE with debug mode for debugging `groovy ` files should I create `GROOVY_OPTS ` with same `jvmArgs `?